# Pyspark : How to create union table for some selected columns from df

Tags: pyspark

I have below pyspark dataframe -

[image]

I want to convert this to. Basically all 3 id columns stacked to each other

[image]

I can do this by creating 3 separate dataframe for each of 3 id columns and then do the union of all. But I am looking for a solution which can achieve this in fewer lines because I have at least 25+ id columns in main file.

Comment: Dont use IMAGE!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by casting **`source_* columns to array`** then **`explode`**.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+---------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------+
#|movieName|Source_1_movie_id|Source_2_movie_id|Source_3_movie_id|   genre|
#+---------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------+
#| example1|          movie_1|          movie_4|          movie_7|  action|
#| example2|          movie_2|          movie_5|          movie_8|thriller|
#| example3|          movie_3|          movie_6|          movie_9| romance|
#+---------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+--------+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.selectExpr("moviename","explode(array(Source_1_movie_id,Source_2_movie_id,Source_3_movie_id))","genre").\
withColumnRenamed("col","id").\
orderBy("id").\
show()
#+---------+-------+--------+
#|moviename|     id|   genre|
#+---------+-------+--------+
#| example1|movie_1|  action|
#| example2|movie_2|thriller|
#| example3|movie_3| romance|
#| example1|movie_4|  action|
#| example2|movie_5|thriller|
#| example3|movie_6| romance|
#| example1|movie_7|  action|
#| example2|movie_8|thriller|
#| example3|movie_9| romance|
#+---------+-------+--------+
```